# Insert rate really slow in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sql-insert

I need help in inserting 2 million rows into a table. The table I am inserting into has 4 billion rows and from where I am inserting has 2 million. The insert rate is around 190 rows per minute.

```
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 5000

WHILE 1 = 1  
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[a] ([a].[col1], [a].[col2], [a].[adate], [a].[importdate])
       SELECT TOP(@BatchSize) 
           b.col1,  
           b.col2,  
           b.adate,
           b.importdate
       FROM 
           b 
       WHERE 
           NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM dbo.[a] 
                       WHERE [a].col1 = b.col1
                         AND [a].col2 = b.col2
                         AND [a].adate = b.adate)
                         --AND [sent].aDate > getdate()-10)

    IF @@ROWCOUNT < @BatchSize BREAK  
END;
```

In the above query, in table a, col1 and col2 and col3 are the primary key (Non-clustered). I want to insert every record in table a from table b ...

The table a has 3 indexes, one with col1.col2 and second with col1,col2,col3 and third with col1 only ......

Can anyone offer any idea about making it faster?

I have 128 Gb RAM on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks

Comment: I think what you want is MERGE()

Comment: Two million rows , I would insert in one batch.

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table? If the primary key is col1+col2+col3 you cannot insert dups so you dont need the not exists clause. Keep selecting the top 5000 rows to insert. I don't understand M. Ali's suggestion. It would create a very large transaction.

Comment: A nonclustered table with a lot of rows and inserts (and deletes/upates) will end up with a 'zillion' forward pointers (very inefficient indexes) and that could be the issue.

Comment: hi @benjamin i have tried with Not Exist and it gives me error of duplicate key cannot insert ... any idea to over come it ?

Comment: Hey @CarlZheng can you best way to Merge , not really good in merge

Comment: you have not answered any of my questions.

Comment: Hey @benjaminmoskovits Sorry for late reply

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits   1- I tried adding with out Not IN and it gives me error that it does not add records .  2- Do you think changing PK to Cluster from Non-cluster will help ? ........ The index are created in history for different apps .... any suggestions to make it faster .... thanks in advance

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits and yes there is no trigger no table a

Comment: Did you try to drop all the index before the insert and the recreate them after ? It should improve your performance

Comment: Hi @DarioN1 I want to do it as a first step . Drop all PK and insert unique records and then add PK again . But my concerns is that on 4 Billion rows it might take days to re create PK ?

Comment: Hi Saad, No, I don't think so... For sure drop and recreate the index will take few minutes but I think that this method will speed up your procedure

Answer (score 0):

Since you want all of the rows in `B` inserted in `A` there should be no need to use an `exists`. The problem becomes one of tracking the rows already transferred in prior batches. The following example generates a row number and uses it to group rows into batches. If the row number is ordered by an existing index then there should be no sort pass required on the `select` side.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @A as Table ( Col1 Int, Col2 Int );

declare @B as Table ( Col1 Int, Col2 Int );
insert into @B ( Col1, Col2 ) values
  ( 1, 1 ), ( 1, 2 ), ( 1, 3 ), ( 1, 4 ), ( 1, 5 ),
  ( 2, 1 ), ( 2, 2 ), ( 2, 3 ), ( 2, 4 ), ( 2, 5 );

-- Rows to transfer in each batch.
declare @BatchSize as Int = 5;
-- First row to transfer in the current batch.
declare @BatchMark as Int = 1;
-- Count of rows processed.
declare @RowsProcessed as Int = 1;

-- Process the batches.
while @RowsProcessed > 0
  begin
  insert into @A ( Col1, Col2 )
    select Col1, Col2
      from ( select Col1, Col2, Row_Number() over ( order by Col1, Col2 ) as RN from @B ) as PH
      where @BatchMark <= RN and RN < @BatchMark + @BatchSize;
  select @RowsProcessed = @@RowCount, @BatchMark += @BatchSize;
  select * from @A; -- Show progress.
  end;
```

Alternatives would include adding a flag column to the `B` table to mark processed rows, using an existing `id` in the `B` table to track the maximum value already processed, using an additional table to track the index values of processed rows, deleting processed rows from `B`, ... .

An [`output`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause may prove useful for some of the alternatives.

Rebuilding the index with a suitable fill-factor before transferring the data may help. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/specify-fill-factor-for-an-index). It depends on knowledge of the index values which is not available in your question.

Comment: Hey @habo Thank you so much for your answer , I have tried to get statics on indexes but as its a online system with 4 billion rows , every time i try to check frag and things like that for indexes . It fails on timeout . One more thing . Can i drop PK and insert unique records and re build PK .... is that good option ?

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes) article provides some additional information about reorganizing and rebuilding indexes. No matter what you do, there's going to be a substantial price. Is there a development DB with a copy of recent data that you can test on? Get some idea of the hit a rebuild would cause and whether it would allow you to insert faster? Determine what fill-factor is appropriate?